# how to inspect CSS animations in chrome dev tool

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, css-animations

Basically All the time I need to inspect how my CSS animation work.so is there way to inspect CSS animation in chrome dev tools?

Comment: Why are you asking a question when you can find out for yourself in literally two button-presses? (Press F12, then click "Animations" in the bottom tool pane).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Chromium (Chrome/Edge/Opera):

- Open Command Menu (`Cmd+Shift+P` or `Ctrl+Shift+P`) > Run "Show Animations" and press Enter. This will open the **Animations** drawer. Trigger the animation to record it on the timeline. The Animations drawer is divided into 4 sections,

  1. **Controls**: From here, you can clear all currently captured animation groups, or change the speed of the currently selected animation group.
  2. **Overview**: Select an animation group here to inspect and modify it in the Details pane.
  3. **Timeline**: Pause and start an animation from here, or jump to a specific point in the animation.
  4. **Details**: Inspect and modify the currently selected animation group like adding delay or changing timing duration.

[image]

### Firefox:

1. Inspect the element that uses CSS animations. Open the **Animations** pane from the right sidebar. Trigger the animation to view a synchronized timeline in the pane. Use the draggable widget to scrub through the timeline or jump to a specific point. You can also change the playback speed and do much [more](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/page_inspector/how_to/work_with_animations/index.html).

### Safari:

1. Open devtools > Open the "Timelines" tab > Ensure that "Media and Animations" is enabled in the left panel.
   Now reload the page or trigger the animation to see the timeline in the bottom panel.

**More info:**

- [Can I DevTools](https://www.canidev.tools/inspect-css-animation/chrome)
- [Newsletter](https://canidevtools.substack.com/p/tips-tricks-12)
- [Official Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/animations/)
- [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVLzkleL_CE)

Comment: Thank you very much. So much details have been given by you and this answer will useful for others as well. And thanks you again for contributing

Comment: This is very useful already, but how to open the original animation keyframe definition, not in an interactive UI, but just show the CSS?

Comment: Good point. I don't think there is way to jump to keyframe definition directly. In the Styles pane, you can press Cmd/Ctrl and click the keyframe name to jump directly to the Source code.

Comment: @IngoSteinke I raised a feature request here, https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/DevTools/issues/90

Answer (score 2):

## There are two ways to open the Animations tab:

1. Customize and control DevTools > More tools > Animations.
2. Open the Command Menu by pressing one of the following: On macOS:
   Command + Option + C. On Windows, Linux, or ChromeOS: Control +
   Shift + C. Then start typing Show Animations and select the
   corresponding Drawer panel.

**or**

### Read the article and hopefully find a great solution:

- https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/animations/